# Java JacksonJSON Как обработать блоки, имеющие в имени порядковый номер

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть JSON-файл, в котором необходимо обработать набор почти одноимённых блоков. Мне известны все возможные его параметры, но каждый раз в файле только часть из них. При этом в файле существуют блоки, которые относятся к одной бизнес-логике, но могут содержать в себе разный набор данных. При этом каждый из этих блоков именуется по имени и порядковому номеру. При этом в каждом файле количество этих блоков может отличаться. Обработать необходимо эти самые блоки, количество которых динамическое, а название отличается только порядковым номером.

Вопрос, как с помощью Jackson JSON Parser обработать все эти блоки по порядку?
Пример полного файла:

```
{
    "name": "Jackson",
    "type": "json", 
    "case_1": {
        "take": "me",
        "to": "church"
    },
    "case_2": {
        "i": "feel",
        "like": "a", 
        "monster": [
            "monster",
            "beast",
            "human"
        ],
        "quoth": "the",
        "raven": "nevermore" 
    },
    "case_3": {
        "quoth": "the",
        "raven": "nevermore" 
    },
    "simple": "not simple",
    "easy": "not easy"
}
```

Из него меня интересуют только те данные, которые начинаются с "case_". У меня есть класс FullFile, в котором описаны все возможные параметры всего файла, где "case_#" обобщены одной переменной "case". Переменная "case" является объектом класса Case, в котором описаны все возможные параметры для блока "case_#". Собственно, сам сеттер для "case" выглядит так:

```
public void setCase(@JsonProperty(value = "case_") Case case) {
    this.case = case;
}
```

Вместо (value = "case_") вписать какой-нибудь (value = caseNumber), где *String caseNumber = "case_" + i;* не получится, так как значение для value должно быть константой. Может как-то циклом прогнать построчно (или перебирая параметры) можно?

Comment: в JSON ошибка: после `case_3` пропущена запятая

Comment: @AlexRudenko да, спасибо, на скорую руку накидала код, не заметила)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь стоит использовать аннотацию `@JsonAnySetter`, чтобы записывать значения `case_XXX` полей в некую мапу, которая к тому же может быть сортированной по ключу в нужном порядке.

То есть, главное здесь --  определить data-класс (DTO), в который и будет сериализироваться заданный JSON:

```
@Data
class Foo {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String simple;
    private String easy;

    private Map<String, Object> cases = new TreeMap(
            Comparator.comparingInt((String k) -> Integer.parseInt(
                k.substring(k.indexOf('_') + 1)
            ))
    );

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setCase(String caseNumber, Object value) {
        if (caseNumber.matches("case_\\d+"))
            this.cases.put(caseNumber, value);
    }
}
```

Тогда для заданного JSON результат будет такой (ключи будут отсортированы по номеру):

```java
String json = "{}"; // длинная JSON строка из вопроса
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);

foo.getCases().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

Результат:

```
case_1: {take=me, to=church}
case_2: {i=feel, like=a, monster=[monster, beast, human], quoth=the, raven=nevermore}
case_3: {quoth=the, raven=nevermore}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!